# why is this code behaving unpredictably?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm working on a console game in which I have the following pieces of code:

```
typedef struct player{
        char *name;
        /* ... */
        char location;
        char traveltime;
        /* ... */
}pl;

typedef struct planet{
        char *name;
        /* ... */
}planet;

pl *players;
planet plan[22];
```

pl *players is malloc'd with

```
players=malloc(NPLAYERS*sizeof(pl));
```

where NPLAYERS is the amount of players.
plan[] is an array of all the planets in the game.

```
players[i].location
```

is the location of the players as a subscript to plan[] if players[i].traveltime==0. If players[i].traveltime>0, the player is travelling to players[i].location.
So when the player is travelling, I want to display a ncurses window stating "en route to (planet)".

for this I use:

```
char *tmp, msg[]="PLAYER 1", i;
for(i=0; i!=NPLAYERS; ++i){
            infobox(msg);
            if( players[i].traveltime>0){
                    tmp=malloc( sizeof("en route to ")+sizeof(plan[ players[i].location ].name)+4)
                    strcpy(tmp, "en route to ");
                    strcat(tmp, plan[ players[i].location ].name);
                    strcat(tmp, "..\0");
                    infobox(tmp);
                    free(tmp);
            }
            ++msg[7];
  }
```

where infobox(char msg[]) prints a ncurses window containing the message to stdout and NPLAYERS is the amount of players. The idea is that this code cycles through all the players, checks if they are travelling, and if so, prints a message stating their destinations.
This works nine out of ten times, but sometimes it gives a segmentation fault at free(tmp), it gives a segfault at malloc or it prints

```
    ***** glibc detected *** ./st: malloc(): memory corruption [a hex number] ***
```

after malloc.
Why does it do this and how can I solve it?

It might help to know that I am using Arch Linux on a two year old laptop.

Comment: You are almost certainly corrupting the heap by overrunning a buffer somewhere.  Either debug this using a memory debugger (such as Valgrind), or post a *complete* self-contained test-case that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `sizeof(plan[ players[i].location ].name)` you are taking the **size of a pointer**.
You probably want the size of the maximum planet name instead ...

```
    tmp=malloc( sizeof("en route to ")+sizeof(plan[ players[i].location ].name)+4);
```

vs

```
    //tmp = malloc(13 + sizeof(char *) + 4);
    //tmp = malloc(17 + sizeof(char *));

    tmp = malloc(1700); /* arbitrary big enough value :) */
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I changed the malloc statement, so that it would reserve the size of the longest planet name (Theta Kaleidis 89) and I've ran the program about a hundred times now. No segfaults, no bad memory. (this comment shows so many edits becuase I keep pressing enter for a new line)

Comment: Someday you will add the planet "Lambda Eridanis 42" and your program freezes again :) You really should come up with a better way to determine the maximum size -- see Johnathan's answer.

Comment: what about tmp=malloc( sizeof("en route to ") + strlen(plan[ players[i].location ].name)+4);?

Comment: That's good. I'd add the constant `sizeof("en route to ") == 13` to the `4` and provide a comment to explain the magic number though.

Comment: I think that will work for now although the struct member as an array subscript doesn't really look nice, but once I've got the rest of the game working, I'll look into stack-based buffers, which were recommended by Jonathan Leffler and Gil. How do I mark this thread as solved?

Comment: You can click the checkmark to the left of the answers on the answer that best helped you. You can also click the up arrow or down arrow to "rate" the answer. Just hover the mouse pointer over the symbols and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The weak point is in the (too complex) memory allocation.

Since your `tmp` buffer is temporary, I would rather use a stack-based buffer using the maximum space that your convoluted sizeof() tries to allocate (as a bonus this will be faster than `malloc()/free()`).

Just don't declare it `static` so several threads can work together.

Answer (score 0):

You don't reliably allocate enough space for your planet names because you are taking the size of a pointer, not the length of the string it is pointing at.

```
sizeof(plan[ players[i].location ].name)
```

That is either 4 or 8 (depending on whether you're using a 32-bit or 64-bit system).

You probably need to use this, possibly with a `+1`, instead:

```
strlen(plan[player[i].location].name)
```

You get quasi-random effects because most of your planet names are short enough that when combined with the allocation round-up etc, you actually have approximately enough space.  It will be when you process a long planet name that you start running into trouble.

Allocation round-up occurs because most allocators allocate space in units of some minimum size, which might be 8 or 16 (or possibly even 32) bytes.  Therefore, when you request, say, 17 bytes, you might actually be given a pointer to 24 or even 32 bytes, and you only run into severe problems if you overflow the 17 bytes you requested by enough to exceed the rounded up size.  You should never rely on the round-up, so you should not access memory outside the range you requested; nevertheless, it usually happens.